# How to set a Parameter DefaultValue to an empty string in ObjectDataSource methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, objectdatasource

In the example below, the DefaultValue of my Foo Parameter passes a `null` value instead of `string.Empty`

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="MyDataSource" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetAll"
    UpdateMethod="MyUpdateMethod" TypeName="My.Namespace.MyProvider">
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Key" Type="Int16" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Foo" Type="String" DefaultValue="" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Though I can handle that in `MyUpdateMethod`, is there a way to set the `DefaultValue` of a string parameter to an empty string ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<asp:Parameter Name="Foo" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a property on the `Parameter` for `ConvertEmptyStringToNull`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.parameter.convertemptystringtonull.aspx